# Validação dos dados com JS mas se existir algum erro permanecer na página html e não avançar para a página php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Boa tarde eu gostaria de saber se alguem sabe como, após fazer as validações dos dados em javascript mostrar as mensagens de erro "falta enserir a password" etc, ou se estiver tudo correto avançar para a página php.  Erro: Quando insiro algum campo errado ele mostra mas avança imediatamente para o p

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--Titulo-->
  <title>BenchKing</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Link CSS e JS ao HTML-->
  <script src="JS\register.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\registerstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!--Começo da class registerbox-->
  <div class="registerbox">
    <h1>Registar</h1>
      <!--O PHP recolhe os dados do Utilizador e é chamada a função validar() -->
    <form id="registo_form" action="PHP\conexao.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar(this);">
      <p>Email</p>
      <!--Caixa de texto Email-->
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Intruduza o seu Email">
      <p>Username</p>
      <!--Caixa de texto Username-->
      <input type="box" name="username" placeholder="Intruduza o Username">
      <p>Password</p>
      <!--Caixa de texto Password-->
      <input type="password" name="password_1" placeholder="Intruduza a Password">
      <p>Confirmar Password</p>
      <!--Caixa de texto Confirmar Password-->
      <input type="password" name="password_2" placeholder="Confirmar Password">
      <br><br>
      <!--Botão enviar ao carregar retorna algum erro encontrado pelo JS-->
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" onclick="return validar">  
      <br>
      <!--Hiperligação com a página do login-->
      <a href="Login.html"> Login </a><br>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>


function validar() {

   var formulario, email, username, password1, password2;

   formulario = document.forms["registo_form"];
   email = formulario.email.value;
   username = formulario.username.value;
   password1 = formulario.password_1.value;
   password2 = formulario.password_2.value;

    /*Testes na consola do browser
    console.log("Voce inseriu: "+email);*/

    if (email == ""){
        alert('Preencha o campo Email');
        formRegister.email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (username == ""){
        alert('Preencha o campo Username');
        formRegister.username.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(username.indexOf(" ") >= 0){
            alert('O Username n\u00e3o pode ter espa\u00e7os');
            formRegister.username.focus();
            return false;
    }else if(username.length > 25){
            alert ('O Username n\u00e3o pode ter mais que 25 caracteres');
            formRegister.username.focus();
            return false;
    }else if(username.length < 6){
            alert('O Username n\u00e3o pode ter menos que 6 caracteres');
            formRegister.username.focus();
            return false;
    }

   if (password1 == ""){
        alert('Preencha o campo Password');
        formRegister.password_1.focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        if(password1.length < 8){
            alert('A password tem que ter pelo menos 8 caracteres');
            formRegister.password_1.focus();
            return false;
        }else if(password1.length > 25){
                alert('A password n\u00e3o pode ter mais que 25 caracteres');
                formRegister.password_1.focus();
                return false;
        }else if (password2 == ""){
        alert('Preencha o campo confirmar Password');
        formRegister.password_2.focus();
        return false;
    }else if (password1 != password2){
        alert('As passwords t\u00eam que ser iguais!');
        return false;
    }

    }

    return false;
    
  }


<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "benchking";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die ("A conexão falhou");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Falha ao conectar-se com o banco de dados MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
 
echo "Sucesso: Sucesso ao conectar-se com a base de dados MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO benchking.register (email, username) 
VALUES ('boacalooaas','asdadasdd')";




if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "Novo registo enserido";
}else{
    echo "Error" .$sql. "<br>" .$conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente remover essa parte da tag

```
action="PHP\conexao.php"
```

e adicione isso na sua função validar(), após todas as validações terem sidos feitas:

```
document.getElementById("registo_form").action = "PHP\conexao.php";
document.getElementById("registo_form").submit();
```